# what does the constructor part mean?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

can somebody me explain what this code does ?

```
Kartenstapel stapel1 = new Kartenstapel(new Karte[] { });
```

*Kartenstapel and Karte are classes.

I have only a guess, but am not sure. It is an empty object created ?

Thank you for notes.

Answer (score 5):

It means that an empty array of `Karte` is created and given as an argument to the `Kartenstapel` constructor which in turn creates a `Kartenstapel` object.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a KartenStapel object, passing in an array of Kartes containing zero elements.